# Run length encoding only for sequence longer than K

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, run-length-encoding

Let's say that we are given an input stream/iterator of numbers (e.g. [2,3,1,1,1,1,1,5,6]) and some number K. We need to encode this into a list of objects. When there are K or more repeats of the same number, we encode with object of TypeA. In all other cases, we encode with TypeB. The classes are as follows:

```
class TypeA {
  int num;
  int count;
}

class TypeB {
  int[] nums;
}
```

For example, for input [2,3,1,1,1,1,1,5,6] and K=5. We return

```
[TypeB([2,3]), TypeA(1,5), TypeB([5,6])]
```

For input [2,3,1,1,1,1,5,6] and K = 5, we return

```
[TypeB([2,3,1,1,1,1,5,6])]
```

Decoding from the list of objects to a stream is really simple, but I am having trouble writing the encoder. Since we **only** encode when the repetition is K or greater, I don't think we can just keep a single list of numbers found so far then flush it into an object when there is a state change.

Comment: When you say a _stream_, are you looking for an [`online algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm)?

Comment: Have a look at [PackBits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackBits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that  keeping a single list and flushing it when repetition cound reaches K (without repeated end) is right idea. Why do you think it is wrong?

Consider extreme case like you second example - all stream contents should be packed in a single list, so we have to store this list all the time, **if output elements are lists**.

If output behaves like stream too, we can dump elements immediately when value changes, and put ending ']' when needed.

Comment: Consider the first example [2,3,1,1,1,1,1,5,6]. If we have a single list that we flush to the result list. When we get to the first occurrence of 1, our list would be [2,3]. We can't know that this list is ready to be flushed without knowing that the next number is going to be repeated at least 5 times. When we get to [2,3,1,1,1,1,1] then we have to partition the list into 2 objects and flush them separately.

**Edit**: Actually I guess if we keep a variable that tracks the number of occurrences of the current repeating num, we would know how to split the list?

Comment: Yes, we need to keep number of occurrences of the last value. When it reaches K, state is changed, and we flush `[0..currentlen-K]` sublist of current list